# Android SQLite dealing with days

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-listfragment, reminders

I am relatively new to Android and SQLite, I was wondering I can create basic form input where user can input his data to be added to SQLite table

When it comes to selecting the day, Monday, tuesday...etc is it possible to compare current day that was added in SQLite to real time day so that for example if its monday, it will retrieve all data with "Monday" as their Day column.

If I want to retrieve all reminders is it possible to retrieve all reminders throughout the week and place them not in an exapandable view but in the associated header day so for example in the same list each day will have a header "Monday" and all monday reminders will be placed in the monday header, will this mean I need multiple ListViews, I will be implementing this on a Fragment

Answer (score 0):

I want to know what you actually want to ask?
1. you can put users' input data into sqlite database
2. put into the db table you created with values(input data & current date)
3. get data from the database when needed, and calculate the date difference and create a listview by asynctask.

i have no reputation to write a comment but want to give u some help. hope you add some comment about what you want to know about specifically in detail.

Comment: Basically I want to query my database that compares real time day to saved day in the Column days. So if real time day equals column days retrieve all data.

For example today is friday: SO if  REALTIMEDAY[Friday] equals Column day[Friday] then bring all the friday data

Comment: okay then you can make a function such as 
getDateFromDB() and compare today's date 
it's not that difficult. you want a code? or a method?
if you want some example code i can write down some for you